# WPF XAML Qualified Property Value causes Exception

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF project where I'm using a simple grid view to bind to elements.  One of my columns looks like this:

```
<GridViewColumn x:Key="GvcValue" Header="Value"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding (cmn:ElementData.Value)}" />
```

As you can see, this qualifies the binding path based on the expected type in order to allow better refactoring, etc.  I also have several other columns that use this system to bind to other properties on the same object types.  Their definition is exactly the same except for the property name and of course the key.  Whenever the grid view is displayed, this immediately throws this exception:

```
Key cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
   at System.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary.get_Item(Object key)
   at System.Collections.Specialized.HybridDictionary.get_Item(Object key)
   at System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventManager.AddListener(INotifyPropertyChanged source, String propertyName, IWeakEventListener listener, EventHandler`1 handler)
   at System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventManager.AddHandler(INotifyPropertyChanged source, EventHandler`1 handler, String propertyName)
   at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.ReplaceItem(Int32 k, Object newO, Object parent)
   at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.UpdateSourceValueState(Int32 k, ICollectionView collectionView, Object newValue, Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
   at MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.AttachDataItem()
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.Activate(Object item)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.AttachToContext(AttachAttempt attempt)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.MS.Internal.Data.IDataBindEngineClient.AttachToContext(Boolean lastChance)
   at MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.Task.Run(Boolean lastChance)
   at MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.Run(Object arg)
   at MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.OnLayoutUpdated(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.fireLayoutUpdateEvent()
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(Object arg)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.InvokeOnRenderCallback.DoWork()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at TestProject.App.Main()
```

However, as soon as I change it to a simple unqualified string binding like this:

```
<GridViewColumn x:Key="GvcValue" Header="Value"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}" />
```

it works without issue and displays what it's supposed to.  Even stranger, I can leave all the other ones qualified and it still works, it's just this one that causes the issue.

I guess I can leave it as a string binding if I need to, but I would like to understand what is going on, or even how to figure out what is going on.  Does anyone know what that one column would cause an issue like that?

Comment: Is it a resource?  Usually, it's `x:Name`...not `key`

Comment: It is a resource.  The columns are dynamically added in the background based on settings on the parent object that holds the list...  However that's implementation details of my program that are working just fine, plus all the other columns define their key as well.  It's something about qualifying the binding path that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This exception is happening because you are using a shorthand version for the binding path, which in normal cases works but fails here.

Replace your code with:

```cs
<GridViewColumn x:Key="GvcValue" Header="Value" 
           DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding path=(cmn:ElementData.Value)}" />
```

Comment: No idea why, but it works, thanks, had the same problem with ListBox.